# Programmatically don't apply the coupon code to x product in woocommerce php

Tags: php, woocommerce

1) A customer puts 5 products of category A in his cart. This means the rule is triggered and the price for these 5 products is now X euros. Now the customer puts two more products from category B in the cart and enters a coupon code that would give the customer 20% off. Is it possible that this coupon code is only applied to the additional two category B products and not to the other 5 category A products?

Comment: This have nothing with programming, flagged as off-topic.

Comment: This is just about settings in coupons  [and you should read the documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/coupon-management/)… Also note that without any provided code, your question is just too broad. Please remember that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.